# py2neo graph.merge() behaves differently from Cypher MERGE?

Tags: python, merge, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

So, for an empty database `MERGE (N1:A {name:"A"})-[:r]->(N2:B {name:"B"})` will create two nodes `N1` and `N2` with an edge `r` between them. The following python code however does *not* do that... but why? Should it not?

```
from py2neo import Graph, authenticate, rel, Node

graph = Graph()

# set up authentication parameters
authenticate("localhost:7474", <user>, <password>)

# clear the data base
graph.delete_all()

graph.merge(rel(Node("A" , name="A"), "r", Node("B" , name="B")))
```

Running that script results in a still empty database. Why is that and how can I get the Cypher merge behaviour from py2neo without using `graph.cypher.execute("MERGE ...")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Py2neo [`graph.merge`](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html?highlight=merge#py2neo.Graph.merge) matches or creates a single node by label and (optionally) property, where you are wanting to MERGE on the entire pattern (node, relationship, other node).

The pattern you are using for the Cypher `MERGE` statement does not appear to be supported in Py2neo outside of Cypher.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example on how to merge a relationship of two nodes.

```
from py2neo import Graph, authenticate, Relationship, Node

server = "localhost:7474"

# set up authentication parameters
authenticate(server, <user>, <password>)

graph = Graph("{0}/db/data".format(server))

# merge nodes and relationship
node1 = Node("A", name="A")
node2 = Node("B", name="B")
node1_vs_node2 = Relationship(node1, "r", node2)
graph.merge(node1_vs_node2)
```

The result is:
[image: Nodes A and B related after a merge]